# Stuck on ethminer setup!

Tags: ethminer

so i have completed step 5 i think but don't understand the rest of the steps, can anyone break them down further for me??? thank you:

5.Using git, check out cpp-ethereum. You’ll want to open a command prompt or PowerShell, find a directory you like, then type this command: git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum

6.Next, you’ll want to switch to the “develop branch” of cpp-ethereum. To do this, in that same terminal, ‘cd’ into the /cpp-ethereum directory (the one created by the previous git command), and then type:
git checkout develop

7.Next, cd into /cpp-ethereum/extdep, and run:
getstuff.bat
This should download a bunch of stuff. You just gotta wait for it to finish.

Comment: I think you are using a very old guide. This seems to be a more updated repository https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum.